# Compiling tar files without configure or readme files

Tags: tar

How to open and compile tar files that doesn't contain a configure or readme file such as
http://git.infradead.org/users/dwmw2/openconnect.git/snapshot/292eb3e0176f9259594902d619981a1131c0f17c.tar.gz ?

Comment: If there is no README, INSTALL or INFO, there should be instructions on the site by the developer who created it, telling you how to use it. If there isn't, you'll have to expand it yourself & look. Instructions will vary on language, and intended goal though clues will be found in the types of files enclosed.  *I didn't download your file*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, the software *does* use the [GNU Autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System#GNU_Autoconf) build system that results in the `./configure`, `make`, `make install` recipe - but starts one step back by providing a `configure.ac` Autoconf input file rather than a ready-made `configure` script.

In general, `configure` is made from `configure.ac` using the `autoconf` program, sometimes using `autoreconf` to run additional configuration tools. **In this case, that should be done by executing the provided** `autogen.sh` **script**, so the recipe becomes

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

(and possibly)

```
sudo make install
```

For additional information about the Autotools build system, see [A brief introduction to the GNU Autotools](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/brief_introduction_to_gnu_autotools/)